# Laravel queues not saving entity to DB

Tags: php, asynchronous, laravel-5, eloquent

please help, I might be doing or understood something wrong.
I am creating a mass upload to database, which takes a little bit of time so I decided to make async all and proccess it in background using Laravel Queues.

In controller I create an associated list, which is passed to Laravel Job.

```
foreach($data as $row)
    {
        $instantArray = array();
        $orderDate = \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($row[3]);
        $issueDate = \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($row[4]);
        $orderRow = array(
            'invoice_no' => trim($row[0]),
            'agent_id' => $row[1],
            'issued_at' => $orderDate->format('Y-m-d'),
            'received_at' => $issueDate->format('Y-m-d'),
        );
        $gameArray = array();
        $invoiceOrdersArray[] = $orderRow;
    }

$job = (new Import($invoiceOrdersArray));
dispatch($job);
```

In Laravel Job I am trying to create an entyty and upload it to database

```
class Import implements ShouldQueue
{
  use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, Queueable, Dispatchable;
  protected $importData;
  public function __construct($importData)
  {
      $this->importData = $importData;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
      foreach($this->importData as $insert)
      {
         InvoicesOrder::create($insert);
      }
}
```

However, every time I am trying I can see in my logs:

```
 #0 app\Utilities\Updater.php(18): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '...', 18, Array)
 #1 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(348): Modules\Accounting\Entities\InvoicesOrder::App\Utilities\{closure}(Object(Modules\Accounting\Entities\InvoicesOrder))
 #2 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(199): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Events\{closure}('eloquent.creati...', Array)
 #3 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php(159): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->dispatch('eloquent.creati...', Array, true)
 #4 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents.php(148): Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher->until('eloquent.creati...', Object(Modules\Accounting\Entities\InvoicesOrder))
 #5 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(636): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->fireModelEvent('creating')
 #6 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(522): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder))
 #7 Modules\Accounting\Jobs\ImportFiles.php(39): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
 #8 [internal function]: Modules\Accounting\Jobs\ImportFiles->handle()
 #9 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
 #10 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
 #11 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
 #12 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
 #13 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
 #14 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Modules\Accounting\Jobs\ImportFiles))
 #15 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Modules\Accounting\Jobs\ImportFiles))
 #16 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
 #17 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(42): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Modules\Accounting\Jobs\ImportFiles), false)
 #18 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
 #19 vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(317): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
```

Whenever I do it in controller it works fine, it just loads very long.
Maybe it is not possible to save entities in Job using queues?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your job you insert the data in the `$this->importData` property.

but in the handle method, you're looping over `$invoiceOrdersArray`, where does that come from?

Should your loop, not look like this?

```
foreach($this->importData as $insert)
{
     InvoicesOrder::create($insert);
}
```

You don't even need the unused `$order` variable in the handle method.

Also, I think you need to `use` the `InvoicesOrder` class in the job. So the whole thing might look like this.

```
use namespace/to/InvoicesOrder;

class Import implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, Queueable, Dispatchable;

    protected $importData;
    public function __construct($importData)
    {
         $this->importData = $importData;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        foreach($$this->importData as $insert)
        {
            InvoicesOrder::create($insert);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, corrected my question, there is a little bit more going on in the Job, but I just deleted everything what is not necessary for the question.

Comment: The stack trace says it is trying to locate your `InvoiceOrder` in the `Modules\Accounting\Entities\InvoicesOrder` namespace, which is the same as the job.  Is that definitely correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process. You may gracefully restart all of the workers by issuing the queue:restart command:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone bumps into the similar problem, check in your entity if you are using any kind of presenters (I was using presentable trait), which adds fields like created/updated by. And what do we get from Auth::user()->id... Trying to get a property of non object, as queue is not an user.